# Print strings in a list that begin with a specific character

Tags: python, string, list, character, selection

Currently, I have this:

```
lst = ['Eleanor', 'Sammy', 'Owen', 'Gavin']

def partition(lst):
    if any('abcdefghijklm') in ([x[0] for x in lst]):
        print(lst)
    else:
        print('This still isn\'t working')
```

I am trying to examine the first character of each string in lst and only print the strings in lst that start with any letter A-M. I cannot seem to find any method that supports this. Is there any native method that I'm overlooking?

Comment: iterate through the list (`for` loop) and check `A <= item[0].upper() <= M` then print.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['Eleanor', 'Sammy', 'Owen', 'Gavin']
whitelist = set('abcdefghijklm')
for name in lst:
    if name[0].lower() in whitelist:
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding what `any` does. It returns True if any member of an iterable fed to it is True: `print(any([False, [], 0, None, 'a'])) #outputs True` Conversely, `all` only returns True if *every* member of an iterable passed to it is True.

It is a powerful tool, however, and you can use for this task:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lowercase #a-z

def partition(*names):
    if any(n[0].lower() in lowercase[:13] for n in names):
        print(*names)
    else:
        print("No names matched the criteria")

partition('Eleanor', 'Sammy', 'Owen', 'Gavin')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the plain and simple:

```
def partition(lst):
    print([ x for x in lst if x[0].lower() in 'abcdefghijklm' ])
```

Or what about the very clear:

```
def partition(lst):
    for word in lst:
        if word[0] in 'abcdefghijklm':
             print(word)
```